# x86, amd64: Why SIGTRAP' ucontext instruction pointer does not point to related int3

Tags: c, linux, x86, signals, x86-64

As the title says - `rip` from `ucontext_t` does not point to the `int3` that raised a `SIGTRAP`. Instead it points to the next instruction.

This deviates from my (naive) expectations that every faulted instruction will be retried upon return from signal handler (if context was not changed and process did not explicitly terminate while in the handler).

On the other hand when getting `SIGILL` - context points to the bad instruction. also on ARM and Aarch64 - `SIGTRAP` context also points to the related `bkpt #0`/`bpt #0`.

Test program:

```c
/* sigtest.c */ 

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

extern void do_int3(void);
extern void do_ud2(void);

void sighandler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context) {
    struct ucontext_t* uctx = context;
    /* Yes, printf() here is bad. I promise to never ever do this in real programs */
    printf("Got signal %d:\n"
           "\tsi_addr: %p\n"
           "\tcontext RIP: %p\n",
           signo,
           info->si_addr,
           (void*)uctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sigaction sa = {};
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONESHOT;
    sa.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, &sa, NULL);

    void (*fn)(void) = 0;

    if (argv[1][0] == 't') {
        fn = do_int3;
    }
    if (argv[1][0] == 'u') {
        fn = do_ud2;
    }

    printf("call function at %p\n", fn);
    fn();
    printf("call returned\n");
}
```

```
; do_int3.S 
    .text
    .globl  do_int3
    .type   do_int3, @function
do_int3:
    int3
    ret
    .size   do_int3, .-do_int3
```

```
; do_ud2.S 
    .text
    .globl  do_ud2
    .type   do_ud2, @function
do_ud2:
    ud2
    ret
    .size   do_ud2, .-do_ud2
```

Compile and run:

```
$ cc sigtest.c do_int3.S do_ud2.S 
$ ./a.out t
call function at 0x5620b87c6908
Got signal 5:
    si_addr: (nil)
    context RIP: 0x5620b87c6909
call returned
$ ./a.out u
call function at 0x557d1bc1590a
Got signal 4:
    si_addr: 0x557d1bc1590a
    context RIP: 0x557d1bc1590a
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

It is easy to notice that for `SIGTRAP` `rip` value point to the next instruction rather than to the `int3`.

Why is instruction pointer adjusted in `SIGTRAP` context to not retry related `int3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is instruction pointer adjusted in SIGTRAP context to not retry related int3?

It's not adjusted by the kernel; the exception-return address pushed by hardware is the one after an `int` instruction, including `int3`.

Keep in mind that `int3` is only slightly different from [the normal case of `int n`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) such as `int 0x80`.  `int` is designed as being like a syscall or far-call, so the (exception) return address is the one *after* the `int`.  Otherwise an `int 0x80` system call would re-run itself forever unless the kernel edited the exception-return info before `iret`.

So why doesn't Linux's `int3` / `int 3` handler decrement the saved RIP by 1?  For one thing, debuggers can do that in software if they want to, and keeping the kernel simple is better.  (For both maintenance, efficiency, and less demangling for software that *does* want to know the address pushed by hardware.)

For another, a fixed offset of 1 byte wouldn't always be correct: 2-byte `CD 03  int 3` raises the same exception as 1-byte `CC  int3`.  And even if you wanted to try, x86 machine code doesn't uniquely decode backwards, so obfuscated machine code could give an address that wasn't the actual start of the instruction that executed.  (Although it would run as `int 3` or `int3` if decoded from there).  e.g. 2-byte `rep int3` is indistinguishable from `add al, 0xf3` / `int3` if looking backwards.

Software like GDB that inserts an `int3` will know what it inserted, and needs to know about the target machine details, so can deal with the offset.

Comment: Indeed, everything becomes clear and natural if `int` family is perceived as a sort of a "call" rather than something that "faults" like bad opcode . This reminds me real mode programming with `int 10h` to call BIOS services, basically the same you said about `int 0x80`. Like your detailed explanation.

Comment: @Sergio: BTW, `int 0x80` is the 32-bit Linux system-call ABI, at least the slow compatible way to invoke it (slower than sysenter), but yeah legacy BIOS real-mode `int 0x10` would also work as an example.  (Native 64-bit Linux system calls use `syscall` with different call numbers.)